# Counting strings from array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, counter

I am writing output of `awk` to array in bash like so:

```
ARR=$(( awk '{print $2}' file.txt ))
```

Imagine the content of file.txt is:

```
A B
A B
A C
A D
A C
A B
```

What I want is number of repetition of each string in second column like:

```
B: 3
C: 2
D: 1
```

Any other solution rather than `arrays` and `awk` is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '{c[$2]++} END{for (i in c) print i ":", c[i]}' file
B: 3
C: 2
D: 1
```

Comment: Alternative solution is: **`sort -k2 file | uniq -f1 -c |awk '{print $3 ":", $1}'`**

Answer (score 1):

Other solution I found:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | while read count name
do
        if [ ${count} -gt 1 ]
        then
                echo "${name} ${count}"
        fi
done
```